# How to specify output format for jacoco plugin for maven?

Tags: maven, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a maven project with jacoco plugin, which generates reports in different formats, such as html, csv and xml. But I need only html. How can I specify it?

Here is some code, where I add jacoco plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    //other plugins
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then I run tests:

```
mnv clean test
```

And all reports appears in "target" directory.

I read documentation https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html, but I didn't found anything about how to pick requiring format. I found it only for Ant and Gradle.

I suppose I missing something, so I will be grateful for any clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today `report` goal of `jacoco-maven-plugin` unconditionally generates XML, HTML and CSV - see https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/9

And in my opinion there is no reasons to disable HTML and XML - cost of generation is small, developers can view HTML in place, while XML consumed by other tools such as SonarQube or Jenkins.

As a workaround if highly needed, `report` task of `JaCoCo Ant Tasks` can be executed via `maven-antrun-plugin`.

Answer (score 7):

You can specify the report format to generate by specifying the configuration as follows-

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.7</version>
  <configuration>
    <!-- Rest of your configuration, if any -->
    <formats>HTML</formats>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note that this is available since version 0.8.7. Useful resource- https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-integration-mojo.html#formats

Comment: Hint: if you need multiple formats, concatenate them WITHOUT spaces like `"HTML,XML" `

Answer (score 5):

I searched the same thing and stumbled over the following issue with it:
The old path was

`target\jacoco\jacoco.report`

The XML report however is put into:

`target\site\jacoco`

and in there are the XML, csv, html ...